# Беден, как церковная крыса

Tags: фразеология

Так говорят об очень бедном человеке. А почему такое сравнение? Неужели церковные крысы голодают?)))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно так. А что им есть-то в церкви? Свечи стеариновые?
Впрочем, правильный вариант поговорки говорит все-таки о мышах.
Крысы в зданиях вообще не слишком любят селиться.

Comment: Бедняжки. А живут там все-таки. Хотя есть выражение: "Питаться святым духом"